# Why we are using "." instead of "(_space_)" to find an element in HTML using above Selenium 4.x version

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

So here is an example:[image: a screenshot of HTML inspect] where I highlighted a part of an html by selcting it.
now my question is while I'm parsing this HTML page, why I have to use "." a period instead of a " " space?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pprint import pprint

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")

events = {}
upcoming_events_date = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.medium-widget.event-widget.last time")
upcoming_events_name = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.medium-widget.event-widget.last li a")

for n in range(len(upcoming_events_date)):
    events[n] = {"time": upcoming_events_date[n].text,
                 "name": upcoming_events_name[n].text}

pprint(events)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to study what "CSS selectors" are and how they work.

Comment: yep, my very first language is Python itself.
so no hands on any another language at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In the above HTML, there are 3 separate classes namely `medium-widget`, `event-widget` and `last`

#### Syntax: tag and class – CSS Selector:

```
css=tag.class
```

#### Syntax: tag and multiple classes – CSS Selector:

```
css=tag.class.class.class
```

- tag = the HTML tag of the element being accessed
- . = the dot sign. This should always be present when using a CSS Selector with class
- class = the class of the element being accessed

Comment: very well understandable.